# Padding and Margin error when auto-resizing divs with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, margin, padding

I'd really appreciate if you helped me with the following problem.

I'm trying to auto-resize my divs using jQuery to adopt to different screen-sizes. The problem is when I try to use some padding or margin, the whole layout falls apart.

The padding + margin should always be 5 px + 5 px, no matter how big the screen-size is.

[**Here is what I want to get.**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zf7d1y91s2vzuc3/jo.png)

[**Here is how it looks like with the code below.**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kgn8kjz6mcpfxl6/rossz.png)

**JQuery:**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      winSize();
      $(window).resize(function(){
          winSize();
      }); 
  });

  function winSize()
  {
      window_height = $(window).height();
      window_width = $(window).width();

      $("#container").css('height', window_height).css('width', window_width);    
      $("#leftArea").css('height', window_height ).css('width', window_width * 0.1);

  }
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
#container {
    background-color: red;
}
#leftArea {
    background-color: gray;
    padding: 5px;
}
#innerArea {
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: green;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id ="leftArea">
    <div id="innerArea"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: you're always want that padding to be 5px or be dynamic in relation to the width?

Comment: I always want the padding to be 5px. Thanks a lot for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this CSS:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/JkmYn/1/)

```
#leftArea {
    background-color: gray;
    padding:5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#innerArea {
    background-color: green;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

---

## update:

you can do it without JQuery and only with CSS:

[**jsFiddle: with CSS**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/JkmYn/5/)

[**jsFiddle: with JQuery**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/JkmYn/7/)

use this CSS:

```
body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#container {
    background-color: red;
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
}
#leftArea {
    background-color: gray;
    border:5px solid green;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height:100vh;
    width:10vw;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="leftArea">
        <div id="innerArea"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

you can set margin and padding to any box that you want just don't forget about `box-sizing: border-box`.

Cross browser for `box-sizing`: [*source*](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

```
textarea { 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it seems really useful. Though I yet have a problem with the left div's height. It should be as long as the red div, which is equivalent to the height of the browser window. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm really impressed that you help so much. It works well in Google Chrome, but Firefox 22.0 is not responding well to the code. I'd like to make a cross-platform app based on that layout, so it'd be important to have it working in all the major browsers. Thank you again.

Comment: Hi @user2311769 to make it work in firefox add the prefix to the css so add the lines -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box;

Comment: cross browser added @user2311769. look at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/JkmYn/5/)

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm really grateful for your help. I hate to say that, but I still have a problem. The reason why I wanted to use jQuery was because I would like the divs to be resized when the user resizes the browser's window. It beautifully works if I reload the page, but it is nor responding to the event when the user resizes the window. Thank you so much, I hope one day I'll know that much to help to other beginners.

Comment: @user2311769: look at this it is with JQuery only: http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/JkmYn/7/

Comment: Thank you so much, it is perfect now. I really-really appreciate your helpfulness. I'm really grateful.

Answer (score 1):

You could use border instead of tested padding/margins:

http://jsfiddle.net/remus/JkmYn/

```
#leftArea {
    background-color: gray;
}
#innerArea {
    border: 5px solid gray;
    background-color: green;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your super-quick answer. To be honest, in the future I'd like to use different borders for the inner (GREEN) div. Is there a solution for that? I really like that current solution, but as it shows on the link, the size of the GRAY div will be longer then the RED container div. (I don't know why, but it won't be the size of the browser window, which I originally wanted.) 
Thank you so much again, I really respect your time.

Comment: No worries! There are lots of ways you can do it, and unfortunately the only other way to get it to work with margin/padding only, you'd be digging into either negative margins or worse, percentage width divs.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with r3mus, just to add, you might have to tweak the height of innerarea

```
body {
     padding: 0px;
     margin: 0px;
 }
 #container {
     background-color: red;
}
 #innerArea {
     border: 10px solid gray;
     background-color: green;
     height: 95.1%;
    width:100%;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It is really helpful, but I still have a problem. 1.) I want to use a different border-color for the green div down the road. 2.) The height of the divs doesn't match the height of the browser window. Thank you again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

How bout this one?

http://jsfiddle.net/beauxjames/dZVEA/

One more little wrapper usually does the trick:

```
<div id="container">

    <div id ="leftArea">
        <div class="demoWrapper">
            <div id="innerArea">fff </div>    
        </div>        
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Even though it beautifully solved the padding problem, it unfortunatelly caused some changes in the entire layout. 1) There is a unwanted padding over the container (red) div, and 2) the container div is not as high as the browser screen size. Thank you so much again.

Comment: Just alter the *margin* on your #container...change 10px --> 0;

Comment: The point was for you to see how the addition of the wrapper gives you more control over placement/position.

Comment: I just had to put that to my code: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
Now it works perfectly. Thank you so much for your awesome solution. I'll be ever so grateful for your help, and also for all of your helps. Maybe, if you have some time, it would be interesting if you taught us in a remarkable comment why it is important to use the Wrapper. Thank you again.

Comment: Excuse me for untoggleing the answer button, but there is a problem. I wanted the height of the green div to be 100%. Can it be done somehow? Thank you so much in advance.